# get control based on position windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, coordinates, parent-child

I'm trying to find out which control i pressed, when i press a control inside a StackPanel in Windows Phone 8. I have tried to look into the Control.GetChildAtPoint method, but i haven't found anything useful for Windows Phone 8, only for Windows Forms. I tried this:

```
StackPanel.getChildAtPoint(and so on)
MainPage.getChildAtPoint(and so on)
this.getChildAtPoint(and so on)
```

but none of these methods are displayed in the code dropdown window that usually appears in Visual Studio. How can i find the control inside the StackPanel when pressed?

There are only HubTiles from Telerik controls in the StackPanel, and i want to find it's name/title when i press it, and i think this is the best way of doing it(correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Use the object property (usually sender) from the click event.

Comment: if i use sender.tostring() it'll only tell me what kind of control i pressed, i need it's content. It's a hubtile - i need the hubtile name/title. Can i use sender.getType()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be this will help you. When you tap on control. Let it be stack panel then behind stack panel tap event get its child. Check below.

```
private void StackPanel_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel panel = sender as StackPanel;
    foreach( var child in panel.Children)
    {
        if ( child is HubTile)
        {
            // This hubtile is the control inside StackPanel. 
            HubTile hubTile = child as HubTile;
            // Now you can access it properties.
            string name = hubTile.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That gets the name of all the hubtiles in the StackPanel. It works though, if it had only gotten the name of the single tapped hubtile

Answer (score 0):

You should place the HubTiles as Items of a ListBox/RadDataBoundListBox. A StackPanel is the wrong control in this case. Then you can use the SelectionChanged/ItemClicked function of these to get the binded data.

EDIT:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataTemplate="{StaticResource hubtileTemplate}">
```

Then create a class (i'm going to call it MyHubTileItem) with properties for the data you need in your tiles. (MVVM)

In the code behind you should create a list of MyHubTileItem content, fill it with your data and set it as your DataContext.
And in your resources (i suggest app.xaml) define the Hubtile as your DataTemplate.

After this you should be able to use the ListBox's SelectionChanged event, to get the title of the selected item.

```
MyHubTileItem x = ((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem as MyHubTileItem;
String title = x.Title;
```

Model:

```
public sealed class MyHubTileItem
{
    public MyHubTileItem(){}
    public String Title {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public String Message {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

For the DataTemplate add the following to the `<Application.Resources>` section in the app.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="hubtileTemplate">
    <telerik:RadHubTile Title="{Binding Title}" Message="{Binding Message}" .../>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I could try this, but the listbox isn't in my toolbox in VS2012 Express for Windows Phone. Can i only add it with XAML?

Comment: I made some changes to my post/answer.

Comment: I think i understand what you mean, but I'm not sure how to actually do it. The class things

Comment: What kind of code would you put in the MyHubTileItem item class? And how do you define all of those things in the app.xaml? I haven't been programming a lot with c#, so i'm a little starter on certain things

Comment: I made some changes to my post again.

Comment: So far it's good, but the app.xaml code gets an error at "<telerik:RadHubTile", the error says: "The namespace prefix "telerik" is not defined"

Comment: Just add xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Primitives" to your Application element in app.xaml.

Comment: It then says telerik:RadHubTile was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assemly reference and that all reference assemblies have been built.
i added xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.C‌​‌​ontrols.Primitives"
under application element in my app.xaml

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to retrieve it's data easy, without any mess or lots of code. I used a ListBox instead, where i added the Hubtiles, when the user added them.

then i used this code to retrieve the HubTiles title - as simple as that

```
    private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MainListBox was tapped get the name of the HubTile
        var current = mainListBox.SelectedItem as HubTile;
        MessageBox.Show(current.Title);
    }
```